# Elasticsearch no mapping found for sort on field

Tags: elasticsearch

> No mapping found for field in order to sort on [created_at]

What does this message actually means? the field by itself created_at exists, should I rebuild the indexes? or is there a way to fix this `error`?

UPDATED :

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "multi_match":{
               "query":"phone",
               "fields":[
                  "text"
               ],
               "minimum_should_match":"100%"
            }
         },
         "filter":{

         }
      }
   },
   "sort":[
      {
         "created_at":{
            "order":"desc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the query you're sending? Probably you're including an index in your query that doesn't have that field.

Comment: @Val updated question, that field exists in my model in django/haystack model,

Comment: @Val further more because of this error my query search doesn't work as it should, I get the results that dont match my query

Comment: How do you send your query? Can you share your mapping, i.e. what you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index` ?

Comment: this is the url i send it to: localhost:9200/elastic/_search/, but what are called "indexes" are fields right? this is a field sorting, does that mean that a field does not exists at all or what? or should I delete all my data?

Comment: Ok, then can you share what you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/elastic` ?

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue with date fields.
Problem is that `created_at` field not mapped properly.

We can solve this two ways

1. Map `created_at` field with correct mappings with `"type": "date"`
2. We can specify what to consider type of field when no mapping found
   in sort part like below

```html
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "created_at": {
                "order": "desc",
                "unmapped_type": "date"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 2):

It could be also if your data of this field is empty.

It helped for me, because I used to use searching in empty data, and Elastic has thrown this exception. After I fulfilled with Data, everything started to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

it is because your datetime filed named **`created_at`** is not mapped correctly in your index that is the reason you just have that field as a string and you can't sort on that field you need to put mapping first before indexing data. for further read about [mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) and how you can create a [template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) for that to auto-create mappings for you.

for [sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-request-sort.html) this will be helpful for you.

Comment: The problem is not that the `created_at` field is of type text, but probably there are several types in the index and one of them doesn't have the `created_at` field. If the `created_at` field was a text field, he'd get another error mentioning a fielddata error.

Comment: for type field text you need to turn on filedata which you can find here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html

Comment: Again, the error doesn't mention anything about fielddata, so that's probably not the issue.

Comment: in error mentioned it is clearly mentioned that if that is a text filed then how you can you put sorting on that.

and also for sorting on the date you must define that as date not text o text fields o can't sort you need to put sort: ['_doc' : 'asc']

Comment: @Val if you have anything specific you can share in here it might be helpful for me too.

Comment: I shared in the comments above. The error `No mapping found for field in order to sort on` usually means that you're sorting on an index that may contain more than one types and one of the types doesn't have the `created_at` field. That's why I asked for the index mappings and we'll know quickly

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is that i created the field with mapping for index which had the field missing and did not push any data.So this eliminated the shards failed error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was querying Elasticsearch via Postman, and I knew the field existed and was being populated for all documents, but I was still seeing the `No mapping found for field in order to sort on [<my_field>]`.

Turns out, I had an extra `/` in the GET request I was making. Removing the redundant `/` fixed the issue.